# How to stop Gutenberg injecting inline font styles

Tags: block-editor

Looking to see if anyone has been able to stop Gutenberg from injecting inline font styles onto the paragraph block via js, have removed **wp-block-library** and **wp-block-library-theme** have added disable-custom-font-sizes and added some new ones.

Thanks